# How to check if condition 2 is / is not true since condition 1 happened?

Tags: function, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to put up a hedging strategy, however, since hedging mode is not available in pine script, I need to make sure the following:
Long entry condition: condition_1
Hedge take profit condition: condition_2
The script I need: don't enter new trade if the condition_2 is not met.
I assume this could be possible through a user-defined function, but I don't know how to construct it.

So, for example:

```
atr  = ta.atr(14)
sma1 = ta.sma(close, 6)
sma2 = ta.sma(close, 18)

valid_long = ta.crossover(sma1, sma2)
long_sl = close - (atr * 2) // long stop loss
long_tp = close + (atr * 4) // long take profit

valid_long_hedge = valid_long 
long_hedge_sl = long_tp 
long_hedge_tp = long_sl - (atr * 2)

if valid_long and 'price hasn't crossed long_hedge_tp since last valid long condition'
   strategy.order('Long', ....)
```

So, I need help with formulating 'price hasn't crossed long_hedge_tp since last valid long condition'.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need something `stateful` and could use variables which hold a state over all bars.

```
var longHappend = false
```

Such variables are only declared and initialised on the first bar with this single line. On each bar then compute the current state. Without any deep insights what you are actually doing there, here is an example how this can work.

```
if valid_long
    longHappened := true
if longHappened
   if <currentCross>
      longHappened := false
   else
      strategy.order('Long', ....)
```

This is actually designed a bit hacky, but you now decide to enter the trDe only if your first trigger occured and no deny happened in the meantime, wich can only be true, when valid_long was true before. I hope it explains the idea.